# How to remove auto select from Mialchimp newsletter signup form input box?

Tags: wordpress, forms, mailchimp

We just recently added Mailchimp newsletter subscription form (Naked form) into our website but if anyone visits our website or any other page of our website the mouse cursor automatically focus on the first input of the form and navigate the page into the form automatically. How to remove this auto focus thing from the form? This is the link to our website: www.bwtradefinance.com

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for the page, this following line of JavaScript is what's causing the autofocus on the signup form field:

```
$(':input:visible:first').focus();
```

Commenting this out should fix things up.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Actually the javascript code isn't on our server, the source is http://www.google.com/jsapi .... is there any way i can just disable it?

Comment: That JavaScript is embedded in the page; Google's jsapi code ends before that. The autofocus code appears to be part of the MailChimp signup form code, so you'll probably want to look at how that was added and remove the bits you don't want.